# Collection read only : Unable to add to set

Tags: map, sobject, set, unexpectedexception

I have to populate a set of Ids with Ids derived from a `List<List<sObject>>` say searchlist. Below code as I am trying gives me System.Final Exception as Collection is read only and prevents me to copy over Ids from `Set<Id> tempids` to `Set<Id> accids`.

**Apex Code**

```
  accids = new Map<Id,SObject>(searchList[0]).keySet();
        for(List<sObject> s: searchList)
        tempids = (new Map<Id,SObject>(s)).keySet();
        accIds.addall(tempids);
```

Can someone please let me know what's wrong going on here?

Comment: Try this: ` new Map<Id,SObject>(searchList[0]).keySet().clone()`. Map keysets are read only.

Comment: Please share correct code. This code is incomplete/incorrect.  for loop don't have brackets. Assigning map to set. I doubt this is correct code.

Comment: @CasparHarmer How should I keep the clone? I need to put inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Caspar's comment explains the problem. You are trying to use the `keySet()` of a `Map` in a way that is not intended: those are intended to simplify code that reads the values and are not intended for use as a general purpose set.

So instead create your own mutable (writeable) set:

```
Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
for(List<sObject> sob: searchList) {
    Set<Id> tempIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(sob)).keySet();
    accIds.addAll(tempIds);
}
```

Personally I would write the logic like this:

```
Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
for(List<sObject> sobs: searchList) {
    for(sObject sob: sobs) {
        accIds.add(sob.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Keith I tried with both of your suggested codes and it's giving the same error.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Well that is weird. If you want to use the `searchList[0]` approach, do make sure that `searchList` is not empty as that will blow up if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I was able to fix the issue with Caspar Hammer's suggestion. Thanks!

```
 accids = new Map<Id,SObject>(searchList[0]).keySet().clone();

for(List<sObject> sob: searchList) {
    Set<Id> tempIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(sob)).keySet();
    accIds.addAll(tempIds);
}
```